# How to save HSV converted Image in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I am reading an RGB image and converting it into HSV mode using PIL. Now I am trying to save this HSV image but I am getting an error.

```
filename = r'\trial_images\cat.jpg'
img = Image.open(filename)
img = img.convert('HSV')
destination = r'\demo\temp.jpg'
img.save(destination)
```

I am getting the following error:

```
OSError: cannot write mode HSV as JPEG
```

How can I save my transformed image? Please help

Comment: Wild guess - try saving as TIFF maybe.

Comment: The vast majority of image formats only handle grey, RGB, sRGB or CMYK colourspaces.

Comment: is HSV a file extension?

Comment: If you can modify the `mode` attirbute of the image, set it to `'RGB'` and you'll be able to save. Anyway, saving an HSV image in the JPEG format is not recommended, compression can damage it seriously.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: The Original Image is in 'RGB'. I want to convert the image into HSV and save it locally for further display in my webservice.

Comment: @Fozoro: HSV is a colour space mode, not a file extension. So when you convert a RGB into HSV using PIL, image.mode will give "HSV" as output.

Comment: What is the format that you want the final file to be jpg?

Comment: @PradipGupta: I did understand and my suggestion remains. But I doubt that your webservice is able to render an HSV image, especially in a JPEG.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: Hi, This is what I did to solve my case:
RGB-->HSV (This I had to save) HSV-->Numpy (now all pixel values I have)-->RGB (mode is RGB but pixel values are of HSV, so technically I can use the different channels as HSV)--> then save to disk. Do you think this is good?

Comment: @PradipGupta: IMO, chances are high that you will get a very disappointing result. Why on Earth do you want to convert to HSV, which is not supported by JPEG ?

Answer (score 1):

Easy one...save as a numpy array. This works fine, but the file might be pretty big (for me it go about 7 times bigger than the jpeg image). You can numpy's [savez_compressed](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savez_compressed.html) 
function to cut that in half to about 3-4 times the size of the original image. Not fantastic, but when you are doing image processing you are probably fine.